# Hadoop Pig Script Help Needed with labeling words in a sentence

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, cloudera

I am working on a solution to the following problem:

Given an arbitrary text document written in English, write a program that will generate a concordance, i.e. an alphabetical list of all word occurrences, labeled with word frequencies.

Bonus: label each word with the sentence numbers in which each occurrence appeared.

Now, I have the first part of this exercise completed.  I am stuck on the bonus part.

Can someone please help me out?  I am using Hadoop Pig on Cloudera Live. Here is what the sample output is suppose to look like including the bonus.

```
a. a {2:1,1} 
b. all {1:1} 
c. alphabetical  {1:1} 
d. an {2:1,1} 
e. appeared {1:2}
```

Wordcount.pig script does the word count and the other one puts it in alphabetical order.

Wordcount.pig

```
--Load data
lines = LOAD '/user/cloudera/gettysburg.txt' AS (line:chararray);

-- Create list
words = FOREACH lines GENERATE FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(line)) as word;

-- Count occurances
grouped = GROUP words BY word;

--Generate wordcout
wordcount = FOREACH grouped GENERATE group, COUNT(words);

--Save output
STORE wordcount into '/user/cloudera/output';
```

WORDCOUNTALPHABETIZE.PIG

```
--Load unsorted data file
unsortedData = LOAD '/user/cloudera/output/UnsortedList.txt' AS (words:chararray, frequency:int);
DUMP unsortedData;

--Put data in alphabetical order
sortedData = ORDER unsortedData BY words ASC, frequency;
DUMP sortedData;

--Save output
STORE sortedData into '/user/cloudera/output2';
```

Thanks,
Anne

Comment: Please provide sample input for the expected output you have posted. And would you mind in explaining how the ratio({2:1,1}) is got.

Comment: The input file is the gettysburg address.  Here is the text:

Comment: Four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth on this continent, a new nation, conceived in Liberty, and dedicated to the proposition that all men are created equal.

Now we are engaged in a great civil war, testing whether that nation, or any nation so conceived and dedicated, can long endure. We are met on a great battle-field of that war. We have come to dedicate a portion of that field, as a final resting place for those who here gave their lives that that nation might live. It is altogether fitting and proper that we should do this.

Comment: Given the example text, the 2:1, in the ratio ({2:1,1}) is the position of the word Now, which is in the second sentence, first word.  In the ratio the ,1 is just the count of the word Now which is 1.

Answer (score 0):

Could be achieved with UDF [Enumerate](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.linkedin.datafu%22)(Datafu) which would be useful to generate sequence number for each tuple in a bag. can you try this?

```
   register datafu-1.1.0.jar;
   define Enumerate datafu.pig.bags.Enumerate('1');
    A = LOAD '/home/hduser/a22.dat' as (line:chararray);
    Z = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(line,'.')) as (word:chararray); // generate line_number with rank
    Z1 = RANK Z;
    Z2 = FOREACH Z1 GENERATE rank_Z,FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(word)) as (word:chararray); // line_number,word
    Z3 = RANK Z2; // rank used to maintain the word order
    Z4 = GROUP Z3 by rank_Z; // grouped by line_number to generate word_number for each line
    Z5 = foreach Z4 {
      sorted = order Z3 by rank_Z2; 
      generate group, sorted;
    } //ordered to maintain word order
    Z6 = foreach Z5 generate FLATTEN(Enumerate(sorted)) as (l:int,word_no:int,word:chararray,line_no:int); //generate word_number
    Z7 = GROUP Z6 BY word; 
    Z8 = FOREACH Z7 GENERATE group,Z6.line_no,Z6.word_no,COUNT(Z6); // output in order word,line_number,word_number,count_of_each_word
```

For word nation below is the output:

> (nation,{(16),(13),(25),(16)},{(2),(2),(4),(1)},4)

in the order `(word,{(word_number1,word_number2,word_number3,word_number4},{line_number1,line_number2,line_number3,line_number4},count_of_each_word)`